# Webpack 4+ configuration

Tags: vue.js, webpack-4

Trying to create the commonsChunkPlugin translation suggested in the migration guide.

I've got this from a vue-cli generated block:

```
plugins: [ new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
  name: 'vendor',
  minChunks (module) {
    // any required modules inside node_modules are extracted to vendor
    return (
      module.resource &&
      /\.js$/.test(module.resource) &&
      module.resource.indexOf(
        path.join(__dirname, '../node_modules')
      ) === 0
    )
  }
}),
// extract webpack runtime and module manifest to its own file in order to
// prevent vendor hash from being updated whenever app bundle is updated
new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
  name: 'manifest',
  minChunks: Infinity
}),
// This instance extracts shared chunks from code splitted chunks and bundles them
// in a separate chunk, similar to the vendor chunk
// see: https://webpack.js.org/plugins/commons-chunk-plugin/#extra-async-commons-chunk
new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
  name: 'app',
  async: 'vendor-async',
  children: true,
  minChunks: 3
})
```

...

And I've translated to this (which is not working):

```
optimization: {
 splitChunks: {
   cacheGroups: {
     vendor: {
          name: 'vendor',
          test: path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules"),
          enforce: true,
          chunks: "initial"
     },
     manifest: {
          chunks: "initial",
          minChunks: Infinity,
          name: "manifest",
          enforce: true
     },
     app: {
          chunks: "initial",
          name: 'app',
          minChunks: 3
     }
   }
 }
```

}

But I have no idea how to debug this.

EDIT: on query from comments I've dumped everything in the following public [gist](https://gist.github.com/DarkPurple141/fa97b4154390bed10f41308f05a56656). This is the original webpack config for webpack 3 which gets generated by the vue-cli. I'm trying to migrate to webpack 4, but it affects the configuration, eg-- commonsChunkPlugin doesn't exist, among other changes.

Comment: Compare your built output and check the both produce the same chunks.

Comment: Problem is I can't get it to build as I don't fully understand webpack 4 config. Really it's a minor change in an app and I'm leaning toward rolling back dependencies rather than figuring out webpack 4.

Comment: It would be best, if you create a little repo we can elaborate on and clearly state what your goal is..

Comment: I've updated with the webpack files in the public gist above @Legends

Comment: I'd prefer a git repo and an exact description of the desired output. That would be something we could work on...

Comment: maybe `vue inspect > output.js` can help you?

Comment: Will give that a go.

Answer (score 0):

i faced exact same problem, i fugured out vendor files in `node_modules` folder and manifest.js file but vendor-async so i checked out webpack 3 version, built it, and there were no difference in chunks so i skipped vendor-async part, i hope it will help

```
  optimization: {
    runtimeChunk: {
      name: 'manifest'
    },

      splitChunks: {
        cacheGroups: {
          vendor: {
            test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/].*\.js$/,
            name: 'vendor',
            chunks: 'initial',
            enforce: true,
          }
        }
      }
    }
```